# Is it possible to use more than one ng-app in angular1?If yes ,In which condition we do it and how to register to angular module

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add more than one ng-app in a application ,how to register the both ng-app and let  me know what is the use of using more than one ng-app?

Answer (score 0):

Only one AngularJS application can be auto-bootstrapped per HTML document. The first ngApp found in the document will be used to define the root element to auto-bootstrap as an application. To run multiple applications in an HTML document you must manually bootstrap them using **angular.bootstrap** instead. AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other.

```js
var app1 = angular.module('app1', []);

    app1.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope)
    {
      $scope.name = "Angular";
    });

    var app2 = angular.module('app2', []);

    app2.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope)
    {
      $scope.name = "Developer";
    });

    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('app2'), ['app2']);
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-app="app1">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="app2">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
      <span>{{name}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```